# Mockito: how to mock setter of a setter?

Tags: java, mockito

Let's say I've a code like this:

```
public response MyMethod(Request req)
{
    String id = req.getFirst().geId();
}
```

I've mocked the main object **req**: `Request reqMock = mock(Request.class);`

Then I've done something like:

```
First first = new First();
first.setId("1")
req.setFirst(first);
```

How do I keep mocking the members, i.e. `getFirst()` and then `geId()`

Thanks for helping

Comment: instead of `req.setFirst(first)` (which will do exactly nothing since `req` is a mock) you'd have to do this `Mockito.when(req.getFirst()).thenReturn(first)`

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for the event (getting the name) and override the return value. For example:

```
private final First first = mock(First.class);

when(first.getFirst()).thenReturn("some_value");
```

Comment: How about `gitId()`? and by extension, if there's more down the hierarchy?

Comment: I've got confused because you put `some_value` in double quotes. I guess what you meant is any expected suitable value.

Comment: Yeah exactly. The return type of the when() has to match the return type of the method call.

Answer (score 1):

You should not mock the method inputs. If you want to unit test your method. You have to call the method with real value otherwise you will not really test his behaviour

Comment: Actually, the `Id` is not the response for this the method, rather input. So. what you mean is I need not to mock `first` and the `id`?

Comment: I meant the inputs. I modified my answer

Answer (score 0):

You want to mock First and have it that getFirst returns the mockFirst. See https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS

Once you have that then you can  stub when(mockFirst.geId()).thenReturn("someString");

Personally I'd skip the deepstubs feature and do what Ole said in the comments

Answer (score 0):

It seems the nested get is more your issue than the nested set. You can handle this by doing the following:

```
Contents mockContents = Mockito.mock(Contents.class);
Mockito.when(mockContents.geId()).thenReturn("string you want to return");

Response mockResponse = Mockito.mock(Response.class);
Mockito.when(mockResponse.getFirst()).thenReturn(mockContents);
```

You can chain these together as long as you need, just make sure each return is returning the mocked version.